# Some websites look completely different, or even detect me as a bot on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

All of a sudden, all websites are loading differently, or are straight out blocking me from accessing them.

Reddit:
[image]

Twitter:
[image]

Google:
[image]
[image]

Really weird stuff. Happened out of the blue.

Comment: Are you adhering to Reddit's rules? Not onerous. Are you using the current version of Chrome?   Have you tried Chromium Edge?

Comment: @John Forget to mention, everything works fine in other browsers. It's just chrome

Comment: Also, not sure how I adhered to Reddit's rules or not is relevant here; this clearly isn't a Reddit issue.

Comment: Maybe change to Chromium Edge for a while

Comment: Seem like you or maybe some software you installed messed up chrome's user agent string.  Tried uninstalling and reinstalling?

Comment: [Hit this URL](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent) and edit your question with what your user agent appears as. It'll be in the big blue box at the top.